# BULK INSERT syntax error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, bulk-insert

While inserting bulk data in sqlserver with query

```
BULK INSERT Table_name
FROM 'FilePath'
WITH 
( FIELDTERMINATOR ',',
ROWTERMINATOR '\n')
;
```

I'm getting error

> "Incorrect syntax near '('."

I don't see an error in the above statement - could someone please help?

Comment: Is this the only statement, or there is something before it?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [BULK INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188365.aspx) documentation, it shows that the syntax should be:

```
BULK INSERT Table_name
FROM 'FilePath'
WITH 
( FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
;
```

ie, with `=` signs between the option name and the value.